# Adding value to D3 horizontal bar graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

D3 noob question: I have a horizontal bar graph that looks like this:

[image]

Here's the code that produces it:

```
function barChartInner(selection) {
    selection.each(function (data) {
      const colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
        .domain([0, data.length])
        .range(colors);
      const maxVal = d3.max(data, d => +d.value);
      const widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, maxVal])
        .range([0, width]);
      const svg = d3.select(this).selectAll('svg').data([data]);
      svg.enter().append('svg');
      svg.attr('width', width)
         .attr('height', height);

      const groups = svg.selectAll('g').data(data);
      const groupEnter = groups.enter().append('g');
      groupEnter.append('rect')
        .attr('width', 0)
        .attr('y', 0);
      groupEnter.append('text');
      groupEnter.append('text').classed(`${c.baseClass} user-answer`, true);
      groupEnter.append('text').classed(`${c.baseClass} count`, true);
      groups.style('transform', (d, i) => `translateY(${i * (barHeight + barMargin * 6)}px)`);

      const rects = svg.selectAll('g rect');
      const labelWidth = 0;
      const valueMargin = 4;

      rects
        .attr('x', 100)
        .attr('height', barHeight)
        .attr('fill', (d, i) => (
          userAnswers && userAnswers.indexOf(i) > -1
            ? c.colors.userColor
            : colorScale(i)
        ));
      rects.transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr('width', d => widthScale(+d.value));

      svg.selectAll('g text')
        .attr('fill', c.colors.black)
        .style('font-family', c.fontStack)
        .attr('dy', '.35em')
        .attr('x', 90)
        .attr('y', barHeight / 2)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
        .text(d => d.name);

      if (userAnswers) {
        console.log('userAnswers');
        console.log(userAnswers);
        svg.selectAll('g text.user-answer')
          .attr('fill', c.colors.black)
          .style('font-family', c.fontStack)
          .attr('dy', '.35em')
          .attr('x', d => widthScale(+d.value))
          .attr('y', barHeight + 10)
          .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
          .text((d, i) => (userAnswers.indexOf(i) > -1 ? 'Your answer' : ''));
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm trying to add a value in the data to the end of each bar on the right side. Here's the block:

```
svg.selectAll('g text.count')
    .attr('fill', c.colors.black)
    .style('font-family', c.fontStack)
    .attr('dx', -valueMargin + labelWidth) // margin right        
    .attr('dy', '.35em')
    .attr('x', 725)
    .attr('y', barHeight / 2)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
    .text(d => d.value);
```

This block comes after the block that handles the data on the left side of the graph. But it doesn't render out in the graph. I'm sure the data is valid because if I sub out the earlier block ('g text') with d.value, I see the values on the left hand side. So why isn't this block rendering out?

Comment: There is nothing in your code with a class `count`.

Comment: Thanks! I was missing this block:

groupEnter.append('text').classed(`${c.baseClass} count`, true);